# How to include tags in createNotification in PushApps api?

Tags: php, pushapps

If you have tags set up in PushApps, when using the Remote API (php) createNotification, how do you tell it to only send the notification to devices with a particular set tag?

```
$data = array(
              'SecretToken' => $SecretToken, 
              'Message' => $message, 
              'Platforms' => array(1, 2), ## Optional, platforms to send to, if empty will send to all configured platforms, don't use this option if 'Devices' or 'DeviceIds' are being used
              'Devices' => array(array(
                                       'PushToken' => $pushToken, 
                                       'DeviceType' => $deviceType
                                       )) 
              );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their API now supports that by Adding **SegmentId** in the request : https://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/API+Reference#APIReference-CreateNotification